# Does btowc(c) always return ( c in 0..127 ? c : WEOF )?

Tags: c, unicode, posix, locale

Is `btowc(3)` locale-dependant? I thought that with `LANG=en_US.iso88591` it would return some european chars for bytes between 128 and 255, but it returns WEOF.

```
$ printf '\xFF\n' | iconv -f iso88591
ÿ
$ LANG=en_US.iso88591 ./a.out
255 -1
```

_

```
int main() {
  int i = 0xFF;
  printf("%d %d\n", i,  btowc(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On my system anyway, going:

```
#include <locale.h>

//...

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.iso88591");
```

causes the output to be `255 255`.  So this indicates that it does seem to be locale-dependent, although the C standard doesn't explicitly say that it is, as far as I can see. (It says that the `mbs*` function family are locale-dependent , but doesn't say so for `btowc`).

Your post looks like you are expecting the `LANG` environment variable to change how `setlocale` is done in the program startup.   That variable affects how `gcc` reads your source files, but perhaps it does not have any run-time effect. The C standard says that programs all start up in the locale `C`.